# Menu option causes program to fail. (C)

Tags: c, debugging, callstack

I have a little text based game i am working on.

The user has a few options of attack sometimes when the user presses "1" or jab the program just stops:

```
  while(1)
    {
    if (round > 1) //First time no pause
        Sleep(500); //Cleans up timing... i like it

    score_round = 0;
    //This is so ugly fix it!
    printf("Round %d: \nChoose Your Attack:(1/2/.../D)\n\n1.Jab\t\tOr D to defend\n2.Cross\n3.Hook\n",round);
    action = getch();

    //Create the damage for each player
        if(action == '1')
        {
            UserAttack = rand() % (UserStats[0]-2);
            EnemyAttack = rand() % (EnemyStats[0]-3);
            break;
        }

        else if(action == '2')
        {
            UserAttack = rand()  %UserStats[0];
            EnemyAttack = rand() %EnemyStats[0];
            break;
        }

        else if(action == '3')
        {
            UserAttack = rand()  %(UserStats[0]+4);
            EnemyAttack = rand() %(EnemyStats[0]+2);
            break;
        }

        else if(action == 'D' || action == 'd')
        {
            UserAttack= 0;
            EnemyAttack = defense(); //Defense randomizes a number upto 3 if it is 1 the enemy attack is 1 point
            break;
        }

        else //Ensures the key pressed is a valid choice
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("INVALID ACTION PRESS ANY KEY TO RECHOOSE:"); getch(); //TODO: Pressing this clears the health screen!
            system("cls"); //Clears screen just in case
            continue;
        }
    }
```

I ran the debugger and all the variables were fine but call stack (which i do not know about returned this)

[image: Call Stack]

If you need more info let me know! Thank you!

Comment: So where is the code for the loop?

Comment: Regarding those 'break' characters - is there a loop or switch we can't see?

Comment: updated the code there is a loop

Comment: @Bevilacque what do you mean _"the program just stops"_? Is it stuck? Also, the `break;` is unnecessary, it's not a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a low value for userstats or enemystats, causing the expression

```
EnemyStats[0]-3
```

to be zero.  This results in taking something mod 0, which is bad.

You might use something like

```
x ? y%x : x
```

to get the behavior you want.

Comment: but then it is just 0 which is ok the attack may be 0

Comment: Yes, but if it is zero then the operation rand() % 0  is undefined behavior.  How could you choose a number which, when divided by zero, has any notion of a remainder?

Answer (score 0):

I think switch case would have been a better option, too many if's are violating the code readability.

Comment: that is a good point i have thought about that but i dont want a switch-case inside a while loop could get confusing... at least for me!

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by replacing the stuff in if(action == '1') {} with

```
                if(UserStats[0]  <= 2) UserAttack  = rand() %2; //Ensure users strength is above 2
                else UserAttack = rand() % (UserStats[0]-2);

                if(EnemyStats[0] <= 3) EnemyAttack = rand() %2; //Ensures enemies strength is above 3
                else EnemyAttack = rand() % (EnemyStats[0]-3);
                break;
```

Thank you everyone for your help and support! I am sure there is an easier way to do this but i like this way because it helps me understand the code for future use a little better! :)